# Struts + Spring + Spring managed transaction + hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, struts2, transactional, spring-transactions

I am using Struts as frontEnd and Spring for IOC and hibernate + c3p0 as datasource pooling.
I am using annotationsessionfactory bean and @Transaction annotation for my persistent layer.
all this is managed using spring beans.

but my data is saved also if i am not using @transactional annotation on the persistence layer methods.

example:

```
public interface CollegeHibernate {
   CollegeWTO saveCollege(CollegeWTO collegeWTO);
}


public class CollegeHibernateImpl extends HibernateTemplate implements CollegeHibernate{
   public CollegeWTO saveCollege(CollegeWTO collegeWTO) {
      College college = CollegeHelper.CollegeWTO_to_Model(new College(), collegeWTO);
   }
}
```

bean is

```
<bean id="collegeHibernate" class="com.velos.p1b.persistence.college.impl.CollegeHibernateImpl">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

session factory is spring annotation factory and 
 transaction is managed like this.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="save*"  read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Throwable" />
      </tx:attributes>
   </tx:advice>
```

This method saves data but i don't make it transactional at all. According to me it have to through exception. I am using oracle 11g and j-boss 4.2 server. What I am thinking is that my transaction is not managed. Any example is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HibernateTemplate allow non-transactional data access (for auto-commit mode), it will create a new Session (if allowCreate is true) and close them after execution of the HibernateCallback.  Most DBMs will rollback  if you don't commit but Oracle will commit them (for you).

To get a Exception you need to set allowCreate to false in HibernateTemplate.

More info: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode